calculate color scale range independently for each facet
I have durations of syllables in Utterances and would like to plot them in geom_tiles. The way I'm doing it below is suboptimal as the color scale is oriented to the maximum number of syllable durations in all Utterances in the data frame.
  library(ggplot2)
  df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = start + dur/2, y = MM, width = dur, height = 0.3, fill = rank)) +
    geom_tile(size = 0.65, color = "white") +
    facet_wrap(~ Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)+
    labs(fill = "SyllDur")


What I'd like to have is a color scale whose basic range is the same for each Utterance no matter how many syllables it may contain. That is, even if a Utterance has just three syllables, the syllables with the smallest and the largest durations would have the same color hue as the the smallest and the largest durations in a Utterance with, say, 10 syllables.
How can that be achieved?
  df <- structure(list(Utterance = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), levels = c("C: [what's] a !mountain! for you:", 
    "NA: (0.554)", "C: ((v: laughs))=", "A: =I don't know the (Schauinsland) is a small mount[ain]"
    ), class = "factor"), MM = c("syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", 
    "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", 
    "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll", "syll"), start = c(407, 
    3967, 4827, 1147, 3682, 577, 847, 4697, 0, 4317, 3807, 1340, 
    5287, 4457, 3437, 4037, 4917, 5517), dur = c(170L, 70L, 90L, 
    193L, 125L, 270L, 300L, 130L, 407L, 140L, 160L, 480L, 230L, 240L, 
    245L, 280L, 370L, 538L), rank = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 
    5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -18L))


One way could be to normalize each rank as a % of the largest rank for that Utterance:
df |>
  dplyr::mutate(rank_norm = rank / max(rank), .by = Utterance) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = start + dur/2, y = MM, width = dur, height = 0.3, fill = rank_norm)) +
  geom_tile(size = 0.65, color = "white") +
  facet_wrap(~ Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1)+
  labs(fill = "SyllDur")


